# div-s inside header or conversly?

Tags: html

I have a question about HTML5-markup: div-s should be placed inside the tag header, article, etc. or conversely - HTML5-tags inside the div-s?
From the point of view of semantics.

For example:

```
<article>
   <div class="noise">
      ... something here ...
   </div>
</article>
```

or

```
<div class="noise">
  <article>
       ... something here ...
  </article>
</div>
```

I need your help

Comment: there is no such rule. its entirely upto u.

Comment: when in doubt see http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on what you want to do, neither is more correct per se. For the example given I'd suggest:

```
<article class="noise">
    ...
</article>
```

Comment: to deceze = thanks for fast answer!  I would like to determine something...  In the source code on the web page http://www.initializr.com/try html5 tags are located inside the div...  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As both `div` and `article` are block level elements, technically you can use it either way. Now it is upto you how you want to code your HTML. `article` is a new element provided by HTML5. I would say, for compatibility reasons, decorate your `div`.

Comment: In the source code on the web page http://www.initializr.com/try html5 tags are located inside the div...   Why is that?

Comment: @buyboy What link is that? It does not open. It gives `404 Not Found`. How is that related to the question?

Comment: As I said, they are both block level elements so you can nest them in each other.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry = in this web-page the html5-tags located inside div-s  and I don't understand - why

Comment: @buyboy No worries. You can have `div` inside `article` both of which are inside another `div`. The answer is the programmer of that website decided to write the code that way. I guess there is no question of `why` here. It all depends on the person who is designing and writing the code.

Comment: @buyboy If you think I answered your question, please accept it.